# styleUrls not working in Angular 2.4

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2.4 and I had some CSS files linked in my index.html file, but they were styling areas that I didn't want them to style, so I decided to link them with `styleUrls` so that they would only apply to that particular component. After doing this, my styles are no longer being applied anywhere. I tried linking them several different ways with `styleUrls`, but can't get it to work.

Here are the files I am using and where they are located:

- app/Dashboard/calendar.component.ts
- app/Dashboard/calendar.component.html
- app/Dashboard/omega.theme.css
- app/Dashboard/primeng.min.css

And here is my code:

**calendar.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'calendar',
    templateUrl: 'calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['omega.theme.css', 'primeng.min.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I want omega.theme.css and primeng.min.css to apply only to my calendar.component.html file, but my code isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Url as

```
 styleUrls: ['./omega.theme.css', './primeng.min.css']
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working either. The styling I'm expecting and was getting before still isn't there. If they link correctly and I go to "Sources" in Chrome inspector tools, then look in app/Dashboard/, shouldn't I see those files listed there? I can't find them.

Comment: Are up getting 404?

Comment: What do you see in app/Dashboard?

Comment: Just module.js, service.js, and component.js files